# AWS SageMaker Autopilot training jobs stopped without any logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to use SageMaker Autopilot. I'm creating new jobs via the CreateAutoMLJob API.

The processing jobs succeed, but the training jobs just stop pretty much instantly after they start. Here's an example of the history of one of the training jobs :

```
Status      Start time              End time                Description
Starting    4/3/2023, 7:03:42 PM    4/3/2023, 7:04:53 PM    Preparing the instances for training
Downloading 4/3/2023, 7:04:53 PM    4/3/2023, 7:04:53 PM    Downloading input data
Stopping    4/3/2023, 7:04:53 PM    4/3/2023, 7:04:53 PM    Stopping the training job
Stopped     4/3/2023, 7:04:53 PM    4/3/2023, 7:04:53 PM    Training job stopped
```

There are no logs available, and there are no errors in the console. When I click the `View logs` button that redirects me to CloudWatch, the Log Group does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Job(s) were Stopped. I would suggest confirming if anything is Stopping the Job. Do you have any sweepers that could Stop the Job? You can look at CloudTrail and see if the `StopTrainingJob` API was called.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what sweepers are, but I didn't create any. I do see the `StopTrainingJob` API calls in CloudTrail, but they don't provide much insight. Here's an example event : https://justpaste.it/9xsnt

Comment: By sweepers I was just referring to some process or lambda function that may monitor resources created in your account. From your comments, sounds like something like that has not been set up on your account? From the event pasted looks like the API call came from SageMaker itself. Did you set any StoppingCondition ?

Comment: Ah, I think that's it - the `MaxAutoMLJobRuntimeInSeconds` was too low, so by the time the processing finished and the training started, it was too late.